# Creating a confirmation box c#

Tags: c#

I am having a bit of a problem. I am still new to C# however I am progressing slowly and learning new things.

However I am confused. I am trying to create a confirmation box. However it doesn't seem to function the way it is intended to.

Here is the code:

```
private void exitToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to exit off the application", "Are you sure?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel); //Gets users input by showing the message box

    if (DialogResult == DialogResult.Yes) //Creates the yes function
    {
        this.Close(); //Exits off the application
    }

    else if (DialogResult == DialogResult.No)
    {
        //Does nothing
    }
```

Comment: Hi, checkout [documentation of MessageBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.messagebox?view=netframework-4.7.2). There are an examples how to use this class. Useful hint: place cursor on MessageBox in VisualStudio editor and press F1 - you will be redirected to MessageBox (or other class you placed cursor on) documentation.

Comment: Thanks, I found out my mistake. It was obvious and funny. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're not capturing the *result* of the dialog.  I'm surprised this would even compile with those `if` statements.  (And if it *doesn't* compile then you really missed an important detail of the problem.  Compiler errors are worth paying attention to.)

You need to capture the result:

```
var result = MessageBox.Show(...);
if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
{
    this.Close();
}
//...
```

Comment: Yea I'm not sure how that compiled. I forgot to declare the var and assign it to the message box. It was a stupid mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Guess this is what you want,

```
DialogResult result1 = MessageBox.Show("Is Dot Net Perls awesome?",
                                       "Important Question",
                                       MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
```

For more details check this:
https://www.dotnetperls.com/messagebox-show